# How I can make the same SQL query whith the halp of Eloqument ORM methods and models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have followng database:

[image]

And database diagramm is on next picture. Simply speaking, Users have many shops, Shops have many products etc. 
[image]

In need to select all products from all shops of particular user. In my Controller it's look like so:

[image]

But it's does't work ( 
Instade of this I try to write direct SQL

I just need to make following request by Eloqument methods

```
SELECT * FROM tmp.products
WHERE tmp.products.shop_id IN
(SELECT id FROM shops where user_id = 1);
```

with dynamics parametrs of course.

Comment: Why does not work?? where do you have the problem?

Comment: Have you created the relations in your Eloquent models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get all products by using `whereHas` filter like

```
$products = Product::whereHas('shop.user', function ($query) use($request) {
    $query->where('id', '=', $request->user()->id);
})->get();
```

I assume you have defined proper mappings in your models like

```
class Product extends Model {

    public function shop() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Shop', 'shop_id');
    }
}

class Shop extends Model {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
    }
    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany('Product', 'shop_id');
    }
}

class User extends Model {

    public function shops() {
        return $this->hasMany('Shop', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this and it return following error:  Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::user does not exist.

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak I have added required mappings for the eloquent query, make sure you also have similar mappings ,Also make sure `$request->user()->id` this should return the user id

Comment: Yes! You are right!!! It was mistake in my Shop model! You are wizard! 10000 Thank you!!!

Comment: And maybe your know how to write this query:
    SELECT * FROM tmp.shops
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM tmp.products
    WHERE tmp.products.shop_id IN
    (SELECT id FROM shops where user_id = 1))  as nested_query
ON  tmp.shops.id = nested_query.shop_id;

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak Can you ask a new question for this query ? Also do add all the details(query,  models etc) in your post so that SO users can get better understanding

Comment: Ok. Just a moment)

Comment: New question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382715/laravel-make-nested-sql-query-with-inner-join-on-eloquent-and-laravels-models