# Laravel, make nested SQL query with inner join on Eloquent and Laravel's Models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have followng database:

[image]

[image]

Simply speaking, Users have many shops, Shops have many products etc.
I need to make this query with the help of Eloquent ORM:

```
SELECT * FROM tmp.shops
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM tmp.products
    WHERE tmp.products.shop_id IN
    (SELECT id FROM shops where user_id = 1))  as nested_query
ON  tmp.shops.id = nested_query.shop_id;
```

I need to catch information about each product in user's shop and info about shop.

About my Models. This is relation with Shop in User model

```
/**
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
*/
public function shop()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Shop');
}
```

And this is Relations in Shop model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

Finaly, Product model:

```
public function shop()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Shop');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eager load your shop's relation(`with('shop')`) defined in your product's model as

```
$user_id=1;
$products = Product::with('shop')
                   ->whereHas('shop.user', function ($query) use($user_id) {
                        $query->where('id', '=', $user_id);
                    })
                   ->get();
```

Models

```
class Product extends Model {

    public function shop() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Shop', 'shop_id');
    }
}

class Shop extends Model {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
    }
    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany('Product', 'shop_id');
    }
}
```

Now when you iterate `products` you will get shop details object in each product object

Comment: You advice add this code into Product model. Am' I right? 
$user_id=1;
$products = Product::with('shop')
                   ->whereHas('shop.user', function ($query) use($user_id) {
                        $query->where('id', '=', $user_id);
                    })
                   ->get();

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak No your models looks ok, the query builder code you can use it in controller, See [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) for better clarification

Comment: It's work !!!!! IT'S  WORK! ))) I understand it, a little bit, but understand!!! Thank you. I have been thinking to make nasted loops when you advice me this way!

Comment: It's look like you are guru of Eloquent